# Is there a MVC SiteMap Provider that supports ASP.NET MVC 2 Areas feature?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas, sitemapprovider

I am looking for a MVC SiteMap provider in which I can specify area as well, along with controller and action. Did anyone use a SiteMap provider that supports MVC 2 Areas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it but there is an [mvcsitemap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex which appears to handle areas, and has good reviews.

Comment: You know what, I am using this already and I couldn't spot the area feature of it till now, may be its newly introduced into it? but thanks a ton, I will try to explore it a little more! :)

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the answer then if this works for you then, so I can get that bounty ;o)

Comment: Hehe .. I was waiting to check this out on my machine right now, I checked and it seems to work fine!, so there you go, the bounty is yours :)

Comment: Ahh .. it says I need to wait 2 more hours!, but your answer will be my pick :)